# Написать функцию, которая анализирует содержимое папки и создает структуру (Python)

Tags: python, ос

Написать функцию, которая анализирует содержимое папки os_task и создает следующую структуру: dir = {"os_task": …}, значением словарей являются:

1. список – если в папке больше одного элемента (который будет содержать словари и строки),
2. строка (название файла) – если в файле один файл,
3. словарь (ключ – название папки) – если в папке другая папка.

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
def objCounter(path):  # проверка на кол-во объектов в директории >= 2
count = 0
path_l = os.listdir(path)
for each in path_l:
    count += 1
    if count >= 1:
        return True
return False

def structMaker(path):
dirList = os.listdir(path)  # список объектов в директории по пути path
for each in dirList:
    path_e = path + '/{}'.format(each)
    if os.path.isdir(path_e):
        dir = {}  # , то создасть пустой словарь
        if objCounter(path_e):  # если кол-во объектов в директории>= 1
            list = []  # , то создать список !!!!!
            dir[each] = list  # и сделать его значением ключа в новом словаре
        else:
             dir[each] = None  # иначе, если папка пуста, обозначить это как None
    if os.path.isfile(path_e):
        list.append(each)
```

Не понимаю как в словарь добавить список из словарей, которые можно узнать, только при "захождении" в следующую директорию.

Пример струкутруы по заданию:

[image: Пример структуры по заданию]

Уже несколько часов не могу решить эту задачу

Помогите, пожалуйста

Измененный код: 14.04.2019

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\ready\\Desktop\\test\\os_task_26'

tree = os.walk(path,topdown=False)
folder = []
for each in tree:#копирование в список
    folder.append(each)


mdic={}
for i in range(len(folder)):
    if len(folder[i][1]) == 0 and len(folder[i][2]) == 0:  # если нету ни папок, ни файлов
        dic={os.path.split(folder[i][0])[1]:None}
        mdic.update({"smth":dic})
    if len(folder[i][1]) >= 1 and len(folder[i][2]) == 0:  # если есть как минимум одна папка
        list=[]
        for each in folder[i][1]:
            list.append(each)
        dic = {os.path.split(folder[i][0])[1]:list}
        mdic.update({"smth":dic})

    if len(folder[i][1]) == 0 and len(folder[i][2]) >= 1:  # если есть как минимум один файлы
        list = []
        for each in folder[i][2]:
            list.append(each)
        dic = {os.path.split(folder[i][0])[1]: list}
        mdic.update({"smth":dic})

    if len(folder[i][1]) >= 0 and len(folder[i][2]) >= 1:
    list = []
    for each in folder[i][1]:
        list.append(each)
    for each in folder[i][2]:
        list.append(each)
    dic = {os.path.split(folder[i][0])[1]: list}
    mdic.update({"smth": dic})
```

Comment: Присмотритесь к os.walk, может это больше подойдет для Ваших целей?

Comment: Появилась идея, но опять же, я не понимаю, каким образом добавить словарь в словарь в данном случае. Добавил измененный код в пост

Comment: Вообщем, я окончательно запутался...

Comment: Рекурсию еще можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, без рекурсии всё очень сложно. А вот с рекурсией - довольно просто:

```
import os
import json

def scan_folder(path):
    entries = os.listdir(path)

    if not entries:
        # Пустой каталог - возвращаем None
        return None

    if len(entries) > 1:
        # Больше 2 записей в каталоге - возвращаем List
        result = []
        for entry in entries:
            entry_path = path + '/' + entry
            if os.path.isfile(entry_path):
                # Для файла - добавляем в лист его имя в виде строки
                result.append(entry)
            else:
                # Для каталога - добавляем в лист его имя в виде Dict
                result.append(
                    { entry: scan_folder(entry_path) }
                )
        return result

    # При одной записи в каталоге:
    entry = entries[0]
    entry_path = path + '/' + entry
    if os.path.isfile(entry_path):
        # Для файла возвращаем его имя в виде строки
        return entry
    else:
        # Для каталога - возвращаем имя в виде Dict
        return { entry: scan_folder(entry_path) }


dir = { 'os_task': scan_folder('os_task')}

print(json.dumps(dir, indent=4, sort_keys=True).replace(": null",": None"))
```